# Is there any preprocess hook for date api?

Tags: hooks, i18n-l10n, theming, datetime

As I asked in above, Is there any **theme preprocess hook** for all of the dates that displayed in Themes Files?
I want to perform some mathematical operations on Dates that show on any content type, 
Is there any solution to achieve it in my **Themes** Files.

Comment: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21date%21date.api.php/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date API introduces several [theme functions](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date.theme/7):

- theme_date_combo
- theme_date_display_combination
- theme_date_display_interval
- theme_date_display_range
- theme_date_display_single
- theme_date_text_parts

All of which can be preprocessed.

If the output you need to override isn't the result of one of those functions, you'll need to look for a different solution (e.g. depending on context you might be able to preprocess a field template).